# CoreData - Store one entity as 'active'

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

Given a group of core data entities (let's call them phrases), what is the best/most correct way of having one phrase as "the active phrase" and enforcing only one active phrase at a given time.

I thought about having a Bool value on the phrase entity, but I don't know how to enforce `true` to only be on one entity out of the set. I guess I could also have another entity (activePhrase) which stores just one record in it but again I'm not sure how to enforce the 'select one of many phrases to be active' requirement.

I fear this may be a dumb question - my CoreData (and indeed database) knowledge is a bit rusty and I want to make sure I'm following best steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd get the active object's object ID and save that in user defaults.

You'd get something you can save by:

1. Asking the managed object for its `objectID`
2. Asking the object ID for its `URIRepresentation` (an `NSURL`)
3. Converting the `NSURL` to `NSData` by using `NSKeyedArchiver`'s `archivedDataWithRootObject` method.

Then save that to user defaults. To reverse the process,

1. Read the `NSData` object from user defaults
2. Convert that back to an `NSURL` by using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`'s `unarchiveObjectWithData` method
3. Convert the `NSURL` back to an `NSManagedObjectID` by using `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation` method.
4. Get the actual managed object by using `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `existingObjectWithID` method.

Comment: Cool - that's a great answer thank you. So no way that you know of to do it all inside of the database then? I was hoping to encapsulate it all in the data model.

Comment: You could create an `ActiveObject` entity that has a to-one relationship to your phrase entity. If you make sure that you only ever create one instance of `ActiveObject`, you can use it to find a single instance of your entity.

Comment: That's what I thought too. It's a bit ick - the making sure that there's only ever one instance - I thought there might be some nice way of doing it. At this stage I'll probably use NSDefaults like you suggested.